# Understanding Property in C#

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I was going through a sample C# (WPF) code where I came across following block:

```
public string this[string columnName]
{
    get
    {
        if (columnName == "FirstName") {
             return string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.firstName) ? "Required value" : null;
         }
         if (columnName == "LastName") {
             return string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.lastName) ? "Required value" : null;
         }
         return null;
    }
}
```

This code block is used for performing data validation. By the looks of it it appears like a property as it contains a `get{}` block. Just want to understand the semantic meaning of the syntax:

```
public string this[string columnName]
```

Comment: They are called [`Indexers (C# Programming Guide)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x16t2tx.aspx)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those are called [Indexers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2549tw02.aspx).

> Indexers allow instances of a class or struct to be indexed just like
>   arrays. Indexers resemble properties except that their accessors take
>   parameters.

Say class name is `TestClass`. It allows this:

```
TestClass testObject = new TestClass();
string firstName = testObject["FirstName"];
```

---

One *possible example* would be **Dictionary** which uses indexer internally. It allows you to fetch value from dictionary corresponding to key element:

```
Dictionary<int,string> dict = new Dictionary<int,string>();
dict.Add(1, "Test1");
string value = dict[1]; // value will be Test1.
```

Answer (score 0):

it's means you can go over "This" by an index. For example if the name of the class is IndexClass you can do this:

```
IndexClass IC = new IndexClass();
string name= IC["FirstName"];
string name2=IC["LastName"];
```

this indexer returns a string and is of type string. You can only right a string inside [], not any other type.

Answer (score 0):

[Indexers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2549tw02.aspx) allows you to add an indexer to your classes and access it elements with an `index` like arrays. All collections uses indexers, and you can also use it when creating your own collections.

But depends on your code,also it can be done with properties:

```
public string FirstName 
{ 
   get { return string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.firstName) ? "Required value" : null; } 
}

public string LastName 
{ 
  get { return string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.firstName) ? "Required value" : null; } 
}
```